# In Javafx, how to bind a string property to a boolean property and another string property

Tags: java, javafx, binding

A target string property is determined by either a boolean property or another string property whenever either one is changed. When the boolean property is changed, a string value will be calculated and assigned to the target property; when the other string property gets a new value, the target property gets that value too. The following is the code I have so far.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class BindingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringProperty stringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
        BooleanProperty booleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        StringProperty targetProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

        StringBinding sb = new StringBinding() {
            {super.bind(booleanProperty);}
            
            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                if(booleanProperty.get()) {
                    return "boolean is true";
                } else {
                    return "boolean is false";
                }
            }
        };

        // Bind targetProperty to either stringProperty or customBinding
        targetProperty.bind(Bindings.when(booleanProperty)
            .then(sb)
            .otherwise(stringProperty));

        // Test the bindings
        stringProperty.set("Hello");
        System.out.println(targetProperty.get());

        booleanProperty.set(true);
        System.out.println(targetProperty.get());
        
        stringProperty.set("Hello again");
        System.out.println(targetProperty.get());
    }
}
```

The expected result is:

```
Hello
boolean is true
Hello again
```

But it prints

```
Hello
boolean is true
boolean is true
```

Comment: Can you explain why you expect the output to be what you state? I would expect exactly the output you get.

Comment: `booleanProperty` contains, by default, `false`, so is always `false`. So `targetProperty` always resolves to `stringProperty`, which is `”Hello”` both times you output the text.

Comment: My bind statement is wrong - not doing what I wanted. I wanted target property to be controlled by either the boolean property or the secondary string property, whenever either one changes its value.

Comment: @James_D, I see what you are saying. I changed the test cases at the end of the code.

Comment: This is still the expected result, as is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76975077/2189127). Why are you expecting the third output line to be `"Hello again"`?

Comment: @James_D, why am I expecting the third output line to be "Hello again"? It's the requirements. Please see my problem statement at the beginning. Of course, "boolean is true" is the expected result with the bind statement shown above. But it's not the expected result for the problem. The bind() statement is what need to be fixed or replaced.

Comment: OK, I see now what you are wanting. I wasn't interpreting "whenever either one is changed" to "change whenever a change is made to the observed properties". Generally speaking, bindings are used to keep state consistent. So your binding will make sure the "target" reflects the current state of *all observed values*. To "do something when a value changes", which I think more accurately captures your requirement, use a change listener as in @Slaw's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76980384/2189127)

Comment: Strictly speaking, Bindings are used to link State, while Listeners are used to turn State changes into Events/Actions.  You seem to want the target property to reflect the value of the latest change to one of several other properties.  The "latest" part indicates something that needs to be an Action/Event rather than a blending of the States of several properties.  Hence, a Listener works best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that expected output, you want a target property's value to be determined by one of two other properties, based on whichever of the other two properties was changed *last*. I would use listeners for that, not bindings.

```java
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringProperty sourceStr = new SimpleStringProperty();
        BooleanProperty sourceBool = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        StringProperty targetStr = new SimpleStringProperty();
        sourceStr.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> targetStr.set(newVal));
        sourceBool.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> targetStr.set("boolean is " + newVal));

        sourceStr.set("Hello");
        System.out.println(targetStr.get());

        sourceBool.set(true);
        System.out.println(targetStr.get());

        sourceStr.set("Hello again");
        System.out.println(targetStr.get());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
boolean is true
Hello again
```

Though if you want to use bindings, you could always implement your own "latest  of" [`Binding`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Binding.html)<sup>**1**</sup>.

---

<sup>**1.** I'm not aware of any built-in API that can make this easier, other than [`ObservableValueBase`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValueBase.html). You could try to use something like `Bindings::createObjectBinding` or `ObjectBinding` directly, but neither gives you access to *which* observable dependency was invalidated (unless you forgo the `bind` / `unbind` API of `ObjectBinding` and instead use your own listeners).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you check your binding logic, you are checking for the boolean property and only prints the custom string when the boolean is false.

```
targetProperty.bind(Bindings.when(booleanProperty)
                .then(sb)
                .otherwise(stringProperty));
```

So it doesn't bother about the stringProperty value as long as the booleanProperty is true.  You turned it to true, but never turned back to false. So you cannot expect the new string value.

To get it work as your expected output, you need to also turn the booleanProperty to false.

```
booleanProperty.set(false); // You are missing this line
stringProperty.set("Hello again");
System.out.println(targetProperty.get());
```

Comment: Consider everything after the comment "Test the bindings" not part of the program. They are just test cases. So, we cannot add the missing line.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you. You mean you cant change the code, but you expect some desired output.?

Comment: Sorry I may be too concise. Of course we can change the code to get the expected results of the PROBLEM. According to the problem statement, target needs to be "Hello again" when stringProperty is changed to "Hello again" but booleanProperty remain unchanged, whether it remains true or false.